# Error 1 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<class-head>'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Hello I am writing a IOManager, but I get this error:

```
Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<class-head>'
```

My code is this:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>

class IOManager{
public:
    static bool readFileToBuffer(std::string filePath, std::vector<unsigned char>& buffer);
};
```

I don't know what I did wrong!

Comment: You didn't `#include <string>` even though you are using a `std::string`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use `std::string`, but did not include `<string>` header. Add this line to the top:

`#include <string>`

So you will get:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <vector>

class IOManager{
public:
    static bool readFileToBuffer(std::string filePath, std::vector<unsigned char>& buffer);
};
```

It should work.

Answer (score 2):

I got this in my C++ code for **unreal engine**. 
It was because I forgot the **semi-colon** at the end of the class declaration
in my header (.h) file.

```
class MyClass{
private: //Stuff here
public:  //Stuff here
}; //<--------DONT FORGET THE SEMICOLON
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey there I understand this has been answered but for everyone else who comes past this,

I got the same error while going through a Youtube tutorial, possibly the same one you have. I did `#include <string>` but it didn't solve the error for me. It turns out the error came from the last line of a **separate file** (picoPNG.h):

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>

extern int decodePNG(std::vector<unsigned char>& out_image, unsigned long& image_width, unsigned long& image_height, const unsigned char* in_png, size_t in_size, bool convert_to_rgba32 = true)
```

What I had to do was include the semi-colon after the last line so it ended up being:

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>

extern int decodePNG(std::vector<unsigned char>& out_image, unsigned long& image_width, unsigned long& image_height, const unsigned char* in_png, size_t in_size, bool convert_to_rgba32 = true);
```

Ben the tutor ends up fixing this bug in a later tutorial for me. So try to check out your other header files and see if there are any places where semi-colons have been left off.

Hope this helped someone!